# How to save the user name and password of a DB connection in cognos analytics 11?

Tags: cognos-11

How to save the  user name and password  of  a  DB  connection in  cognos  analytics 11 ??
I  don't want it every time ask me user name and password
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3riL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'Use the following signon' option.

[image]

Comment: You save my life.  I know that you also answer my other questions.  Thanks  a lot. :)  Hope all your New Year dreams come true!